# How to toggle Group hover on click in tailwind Css/React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have followed [This](https://caffeinecreations.ca/blog/navbar-with-hovers-dropdown-using-tailwind/#:%7E:text=To%20begin%20you%20need%20to,display%20in%20the%20variants%20section.&text=The%20navigation%20is%20then%20relative,responsive%20hamburger%20menu%20set%20up.) Tutorial to create a Navigation menu which displays list of menu on hover and closes when we hover off of the entire group.
But I have been instructed that it should also be able to close whenever something is clicked inside that group how can I do achieve that?. Is there a tailwind class that toggles the hover state when clicked or is there any other approaches Either from React/Javascript/Css approach to do this.

Along with hover how can I also toggle the display of the menu when a click event occurs on the nav menu

```
<nav aria-label="primary" class="relative z-20 flex-col flex-grow hidden pb-4 md:pb-0 md:flex md:justify-end md:flex-row">
  
  <div class="relative group">
      <button class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-4 mt-2 text-base font-bold text-left uppercase bg-transparent rounded-lg md:w-auto md:inline md:mt-0 md:ml-4 focus:outline-none font-montserrat">
          <span>First Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <div class="absolute z-10 hidden bg-grey-200 group-hover:block">
          
          <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-4 bg-white bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-2">
              <p>
                dropdown content here
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>  
  
  <div class="relative group">
      <button class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-4 mt-2 text-base font-bold text-left uppercase bg-transparent rounded-lg md:w-auto md:inline md:mt-0 md:ml-4 focus:outline-none font-montserrat">
          <span>Second Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <div class="absolute z-10 hidden bg-grey-200 group-hover:block">
          
          <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-4 bg-white bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-2">
              <p>
                dropdown content here
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>   
</nav>
```

`

Comment: You can use the [focus-within](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#focus-within) state. Another option is to implement some sort of JS solution

Comment: @Reyno could you please show me how i can do this with focus-within?

Comment: The link I gave you literally shows you how to do it. -> `group-focus-within:block`

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the click on the `group`, and then remove the `group-hover:block` class. Then "reset" and re-add the `group-hover:block` when the mouse is no longer hovering:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.group').forEach((group) =>
  group.addEventListener('click', ({ currentTarget }) => {
    const show = currentTarget.querySelector('.group-hover\\:block');
    show.classList.remove('group-hover:block');

    currentTarget.addEventListener(
      'mouseleave',
      () => {
        show.classList.add('group-hover:block');
      },
      { once: true },
    );
  }),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<nav aria-label="primary" class="relative z-20 flex-col flex-grow hidden pb-4 md:pb-0 md:flex md:justify-end md:flex-row">
  <div class="relative group">
    <button class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-4 mt-2 text-base font-bold text-left uppercase bg-transparent rounded-lg md:w-auto md:inline md:mt-0 md:ml-4 focus:outline-none font-montserrat">
      <span>First Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <div class="absolute z-10 hidden bg-grey-200 group-hover:block">
      <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-4 bg-white bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-2">
          <p>dropdown content here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="relative group">
    <button class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-4 mt-2 text-base font-bold text-left uppercase bg-transparent rounded-lg md:w-auto md:inline md:mt-0 md:ml-4 focus:outline-none font-montserrat">
      <span>Second Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <div class="absolute z-10 hidden bg-grey-200 group-hover:block">
      <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-4 bg-white bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-2">
          <p>dropdown content here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

For how can you can also toggle the display of the menu when a click event occurs on the nav menu, I decided not to answer this as posts should be limited to one question only (consider creating a separate post) and because I found this question ambiguous.